# error in sqlite select statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
SELECT DISTINCT _id, Game_name, Book, Chapter, Verse_start, Verse_stop, Scripture 
FROM Bible_Game WHERE God's Kingdom
```

i have above code in sqlite select statement and it gives me following error.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'s Kingdom": , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, Game_name, Book, Chapter, Verse_start, Verse_stop, Scripture FROM Bible_Game WHERE God's Kingdom
```

how can i solve this problem (how can i use escape character in sqlite?)

Comment: `WHERE God's Kingdom` is meaningless. Which field are you trying to match it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, your filtering condition (after the WHERE) is not correct.  It must compare a column to a value.  I'm guessing that you're searching for a record with Game_name equal to the phrase *God's Kingdom*, is that correct?

Additionally, text strings must appear in single quotes.  Any internal single quotes within the string must be escaped by doubling the quote character.

If my assumption about your intention is correct, the proper SQL to use is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT _id, Game_name, Book, Chapter, Verse_start, Verse_stop, Scripture 
 FROM Bible_Game WHERE Game_name = 'God''s Kingdom'
```

Comment: almost good ... but we shouldnt assuming that `'` is escape char so it is better to use parameters ...

Comment: SQL always escapes quotes by doubling them, therefore if you're writing an SQL statement with a specified value it's safe and correct to write the command as above.  Parameterized queries are appropriate where you're accepting user input for the comparison value — and not because the escaping character might change but because the user might be attempting to inject malicious SQL into your command.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was a silly mistake. thanks to pointing it out.... cheers. now it works perfectly. btz in @zapl's answer, i dnt have to worry about quotes....

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get rid of problems with `'` is to escaper them via `selectionArgs` provided by every database method in Android:

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT _id, Game_name, Book, Chapter, " +
        "Verse_start, Verse_stop, Scripture FROM Bible_Game WHERE Game_name=?",
        new String[] { "God's Kingdom" });
```

results in

```
... WHERE Game_name='God''s Kingdom'
```